# Setting page visible to true fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SPA application.  The application is wizard like.  However, I am putting code in place to accept from an app data that would allow the user to by pass several screens since the app will pass the required data to the page. For the page to load it must be visible.  However, when I try to set it to visible it still returns visible = false.

This is a .Net 4.7.1 build. Below is the code:`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var isFromSSO = Request.QueryString["sso"].ToStringValueOrEmptyString().ToBool();
        if (PendingAppt.FirstName.IsNotNullOrEmpty() && PendingAppt.LastName.IsNotNullOrEmpty() && PendingAppt.Email.IsNotNullOrEmpty() && isFromSSO)
    {
        NavPageValidate.Status = PageStatusEnum.Complete;
            NavPageStart.Status = PageStatusEnum.Complete;
            utilityLib.LogString(NavPageValidate.Status + ", " + NavPageStart.Status);
            this.Visible = true;
    }
        if (this.Visible)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        utilityLib.LogString("Loading Page ");
                LoadPage();
    }
    else
    {
      SavePage();
    }
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to identify why the page this.Visible = true; fails to set the page to true.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that `this.Visible = true;` is being executed? It seems to have a lot of cases where it might not be.

Comment: I have debugged the page.  When the conditions of the first if statement is true, it does execute the code to set it to true.  otherwise it executes as it normally would.